# creating nested json object using java

Tags: java, json

I have an example `JSON` object that I would like to create using Java. How would I accomplish this using son-"simple-1.1.1.jar"?

```
{
 "name": "country",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "USA",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "person",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "women",
       "children":[
         {"name":"sara", "age": 29},
         {"name":"jiya", "age": 75},
         {"name":"yena", "age": 43}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "men",
       "children":[
         {"name":"mickal", "age": 46},
         {"name":"joseph", "size": 45},
         {"name":"graham", "size": 43},
         {"name":"ronaldo", "size": 63}
       ]
      }
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "india",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "women",
       "children":[
         {"name":"priya", "size": 76},
         {"name":"sonal", "size": 75},
         {"name":"yena", "size": 73}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "men",
       "children":[
         {"name":"raj", "size": 46},
         {"name":"dev", "size": 45},
         {"name":"hari", "size": 43},
         {"name":"vel", "size": 63}
       ]
      }
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: You need to use combination of `JSONObject` and `JSONArray` classes.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy to convert from Java Object to JSON and vice versa through Jackson converter. Please see the below code 
        //jackson conversion.
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
        Book b3 = mapper.readValue(new File("book.json"), Book.class);//reads json from file and convert to Book object
        System.out.println("jackson b3-"+b3);

```
    Book b1 = new Book(1, "Learn Java", d1, "James Gosling", 23.50);
    mapper.writeValue(new File("book.json"), b1);  // write java to json object file.
```

below jars are required
    import org.codehaus.jackson.*;
    import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;